# When using the indirect function it does not move data down with it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a back end of data in my workbook, the sheet is called "Task List". This is just a list of tasks listed in this sheet in column A.

Then I have 4 separate sheets that reference these tasks with the =indirect("'Task List'!A"&ROW()-5) function and in these 4 sheets. My problem is that in the 4 sheets, each row has a list of data that goes with it, so when a new task is added in the "task list" sheet (added between cells), the data does not move downward with the task, instead, the data stays put while just the task list moves down...to explain more clearly i have shown this below:

```
Task List               Data Sheet 1   Data Items
task 1                  Task 1         Data 1
task 2                  Task 2         Data 2 
task 3                  Task 3         Data 3
task 4                  Task 4         Data 4
task 5                  Task 5         Data 5
```

Now when a new task is inserted....

```
Task List                  Data Sheet 1             Data Items
task 1                     task 1                   Data 1
task 2                     task 2                   Data 2
NEW TASK INSERTED HERE     NEW TASK INSERTED HERE   Data 3
task 3                     task 3                   Data 4
task 4                     task 4                   Data 5
task 5                     task 5                   BLANK
```

As you can see, the data stays put above in the example. Is there any way to make data move with the indirect funcction or is there a better way of doing this? - The reason the sheet is build this way is that the tasks in the task list have to go into 5 sheets and it saves time having to copy the task into each sheet when a new one has to be added.

Comment: 'Make data move with the indirect function' means dont use INDIRECT, just use a regular direct reference. INDIRECT, in the way you have laid it out, stays pointed at the *grid location* not the unique 'cell ID'.

Comment: This was the problem I was having in my other post which you solved, if I use a direct reference and you add a task to the task list, it does not include the new task in the task lists

Comment: That's basically the trade-off - if you want a cell to reference an exact 'cell ID', you need to use a direct reference. This keeps it locked on the 'correct' cell even if a row is added or deleted. If you insert a row and want to account for it on your other sheet, you will need to insert a row there and copy the formulas to account for it. See my possible solution below which allows you to use INDIRECT references for the unique IDs, with INDEX/MATCH to pull in the appropriate info for a given task name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are committed to using the INDIRECT method of referencing the cells, consider adding in a method of indexing your data and pulling in your other columns based on the Task name.

For example - assume that in all sheets, column A holds the unique task name.

In column B on your data items tab, if you want to pull in the data associated with the unique task name in column A from one of your other sheets, you can do so as follows [shown for B2]:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))
```

If you copy this down and right it will automatically pick up all cells in that order, matched by the unique ID, which uses an INDIRECT reference to always point to a given Grid reference.